# Drag & Drop for Tab URL using the lock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I know that it is possible to drag this lock to open the tab in a new location (where it is released). But how do I detect this in Javascript? This is not an event that occurs (starts) within the application's document so not sure how to know a drag event started and thus tell when it ends.

I would like to simply grab the URL when a user drops this item into a droppable div/container. Hoping for a solution that works for Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this drag event allows you to “copyLink” and drop it on any input that has text type (input/text area). You can see this by dropping the dragged object into the URL address bar or even dev tools console. You should get the full URL of the dragged object.

Fun fact, when you drag this object you can then navigate to different tabs by hovering over them. You will see a small arrow confirming which tab will be entered.